# Replace URL with different string

Tags: mariadb-10.3

I try to replace all my URL with another into my mariadb database (10.3.31)

URL's Example :

```
https://website.com/download/8fd4g8er4ger5f84/filename.zip
https://website.com/download/fggf4hf5gh4/filename.zip
https://website.com/download/1v8t77hth/filename.zip
https://website.com/download/fgh48rt4g/filename.zip
```

I want to replace : `https://website.com/download/8fd4g8er4ger5f84` (< this using different hash folder name)
with my new URL : `https://newurl.com/download/filename.zip`

I used "update / replace" SQL command in the past, but I don't know how to do with unique hash name folder like above

Help me please?

---

EDIT : Found it

Found it :

UPDATE table_name SET column_name = REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name, 'website.com/download/(.*?)/', 'NEWwebsite.com/download/')

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex in this case

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name, 'website.com/download/(.*?)/', 'newUrl.com/download/');
```

Comment: Let me know if this doesn't work or doesn't answer the question. I haven't used MariaDB before but I am pretty familiar with SQL in general

Comment: Thank you for answering. But i have many different url not only one.

Comment: Does the URL you are setting it to change as well? Or will they all be https://newurl.com/download/filename.zip

Comment: I suppose my question would be better asked. Are you changing the domain to something and keeping the filenames the same? Are you changing them both? It would be easier I think if you were changing the domain name and it was the same change every time. Filenames however obviously change for every file

Comment: I have around 8000 URL with different name and different folder name :

Example : https://website.com/download/8fd4g8er4ger5f84/namedifferent.zip

https://website.com/download/fggf4hf5gh4/namedifferent.zip

https://website.com/download/1v8t77hth/namedifferent.zip

https://website.com/download/fgh48rt4g/namedifferent.zip


only https://website.com/download/ is same

I need to keep filename.zip and change the rest

My problem is I don't know how to change these url with different folder name (8fd4g8er4ger5f84 / fggf4hf5gh4 / 1v8t77hth / fgh48rt4g / etc.)

Comment: I know this is something like that :

UPDATE 
  `sql_table` 
SET 
  `column_name` = REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name, 
                'website.com/download/8fd4g8er4ger5f84/', 
                'NEWwebsite.com/download/')

But I don't know how to manage folder diferrent named like > 8fd4g8er4ger5f84 or dff8f4zef or fd8g41r8f4e or 4fd84dfg or fd8g78fdg or v4c587gz  etc

Comment: Is 'website.com/download/*/' syntax is good ?

Comment: Found it :

UPDATE table_name SET column_name = REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name, 'website.com/download/(.*?)/', 'NEWwebsite.com/download/')

It is easy .. but i'm noob :D
Hope this can help someone :)

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I am going to update my answer so that the community finds it more helpful @NuxMr

Comment: alright thx for your help btw :)